# Read indices stored in a list

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, variable-length

I have a dataset which is stored as a list. I want to be able to retrieve different pieces of the data and alter them. The indices of pieces I need are stored in a different list.

For example:

```
data_list = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[5,6]]
indices = [[0,0,1],[1,0]]
```

In this case I might want to retrieve `data_list[0][0][1]` and `data_list[1][0]` and change them to value `6`, but I cannot simply do `data_list[indices[0]] = 6`. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to loop over all the keys/sub-keys until you get the data you need.

What you can do is set a variable to a reference to the `data_list` and loop over the indexes and shift the reference until it's pointing to the lowest nested list.

Then you can set the value in that lowest list to whatever value you need.

```
data_list = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[5,6]]
indices = [[0,0,1],[1,0]]

for *path, final in indices:
    val = data_list

    for i in path:
        val = val[i]

    val[final] = 6

print(data_list)
```

Comment: Extremely minor tweak that arguably makes the code look a little nicer: Have the outer `for` loop split the rest of the indices from the final index. `for *rest, last in indices:`, `val = data_list`, `for i in rest: val = val[i]`, `val[last] = 6`. Not a big deal, but I dislike nesting lookups as in `val[index[-1]]` like that.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm actually still learning Python, so thanks for the suggestion of `for *rest, last in indices`.  I knew you could unpack values in a `for` loop, didn't realize you could use `*rest` there :-)

Comment: Yeah, it was added in Python 3 with [PEP 3132: Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). Which was then further extended by [PEP 448: Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) to give us such gems as merging two `dict`s to a new `dict` as an expression (`{**d1, **d2}`) and the empty `set` "literal", aka the one-eyed monkey operator (`{*()}`). :-) Main problem is that neither feature is well-documented or easily searchable (searching for `*` being notoriously difficult).

Comment: @ShadowRanger `one-eyed monkey`, I love it!